# I want to access the value of Gurobi Variable

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to access the value of gurobi variable self.a and self.b here but its returning 0.0. How can I access the value of these variables. The code is below

```
from gurobipy import GRB, Model

class abc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()

    def creatingvarriables(self):
        self.a = self.model.addVar(lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="y_")
        self.b = self.model.addVar(lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="q_")
        self.model.update()

    def constraint1(self):
        lhs1 = self.model.getVarByName("y_")
        lhs1 = 2
        rhs1 = self.model.getVarByName("q_")
        rhs1 = 3
        self.model.update()
        self.model.addConstr(lhs1, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, rhs1)

    def printvalues(self):
        self.model.optimize()
        #self.model.printAttr('')
        print self.a.X
        print self.b.X

if __name__ == "__main__":
    newobject = abc()
    newobject.creatingvarriables()
    newobject.constraint1()
    newobject.printvalues()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it's value by calling the variable's `*.X` attribute, as explained in [GUROBI's documentation](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/). For reference, the direct link to the attribute: [X Attribute](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/x.html#attr:X)

Comment: Thats the thing.. i am using .X to inquire value but its returning 0.0 while i have assigned the value 2

Comment: Optimize a model with 1 rows, 2 columns and 0 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Objective range  [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+00]
Presolve removed 1 rows and 2 columns
Presolve time: 0.02s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    0.0000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 0 iterations and 0.03 seconds
Optimal objective  0.000000000e+00
[0.0, 0.0]

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly accessing the variable values through the `X` attribute.  The reason why you get confused by the zero solution is an error in the method `constraint1`:

```
lhs1 = self.model.getVarByName("y_")
lhs1 = 2
rhs1 = self.model.getVarByName("q_")
rhs1 = 3
self.model.update()
self.model.addConstr(lhs1, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, rhs1)
```

First you assign to `lhs1` and `rhs1` references to the created variables, but then you overwrite them with numbers.  Effectively you are adding the constraint `2 <= 3`, which is satisfied independently of `y_` and `q_`.  Hence, setting `y_` and `q_` to zero is an optimal solution.